# How to convert Instant to joda DateTime?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, java-time

How to convert Instant(java.time.Instant) to joda DateTime (org.joda.time.DateTime)? Or rather, what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
new DateTime( myInstant.toEpochMilli() )
```

## *java.time* replaces *Joda-Time*

Do you understand that *java.time* is the successor to *Joda-Time*? If you have *java.time* at your disposal, there should be no need to use *Joda-Time*. The same man, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen), led both projects, taking lessons learned from *Joda-Time* to design *java.time* in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

## Convert by way of count of milliseconds

But to answer your Question directly: [Extract from the `Instant` object a count of milliseconds](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli(long)) since the first moment of 1970 in UTC. Use that count to [construct a `DateTime`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime-long-) object.

Beware of potential data loss. An `Instant` may contain microseconds or nanoseconds. These will be ignored, of course, when extracting milliseconds.

```
java.time.Instant myInstant = Instant.now() ; 
long millis = myInstant.toEpochMilli() ;
org.joda.time.DateTime dt = new DateTime( millis ) ;
```

In *java.time*, an `Instant` is always in UTC. To match that on your `DateTime`, pass the [`UTC`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#UTC) constant to [this other constructor](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime-long-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-).

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime( millis , DateTimeZone.UTC ) ;
```

Comment: I have an `Instant`, and I need to pass `DateTime` to a dependency. I guess this should work `new DateTime(myInstantVar.toEpochMilli())`.

Comment: /**
     * Constructs an instance set to the milliseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
     * using <code>ISOChronology</code> in the default time zone.
     *
     * @param instant  the milliseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
     */
    public DateTime(long instant) {
        super(instant);
    }

Comment: Thanks you sir, you helped me quick with my issue :)